# Bootstrap : Datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following code for date picker. But its not working.

My code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Production Year</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
            <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text" class="datepicker"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-calendar" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Jquery as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Removing ruby and rails flags.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `class` attribute and using `#` selector which is for id, it won't work. Use `.datepicker` like so:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
when we include any other .js file then be sure to include  first jquery.min.js.

2.
and if you  are including .js file for datepicker more then one time then it will override previous file and datepicker will not work.